# access the variable in my javascript from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my CSHTML I have some JavaScript which contains a string variable.  How do I access this variable from my controller?

Answer (score 4):

When you invoke the controller you could pass it as parameter. For example if you are invoking the controller action using AJAX:

```
$.post('/someaction', { someValue: someVariable }, function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult someAction(string id)
{
return Content("got it");
}
```

in script

```
$(function(){

var someid='12';
$.post('/Controller/someAction',{id:someid},function(data){
//this call back is executed upon successfull POST
console.log(data); // got it"

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hidden input field in your form valorized with the value of your string variable. When you post the form you can read the value as usual.